# How to prove that the set of maximal elements of a set of prime ideals is finite

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a subset of ${\rm Spec}(R)$ with $R$ noetherian

Are there any techniques to prove that ${\rm max}(A)$ (ie the set of maximal elements of $A$) is finite?

I'm looking for **equivalent conditions** or conditions that **imply** this finiteness.

Particularly I'm thinking on the case $A:={\rm Ass}_R(M)$

Comment: If A=Ass(M) and max A is finite then the zero divisors of M are a finite union of primes. I need this to solve a problem

Answer (score -1):

there are different ways:
Matsumura:
from

[image]

and

[image]

Concludes

[image]

---

Sharp in "Steps in Commutative Algebra" uses *minimal primary
decomposition* of modules (see 9.25 - 9.33)

Comment: I don't want to prove that $A$ itself is finite but its maximal elements!

Comment: when A itself is finite so is its maximal elements!

Comment: That's trivial. I'm asking on the case A is not finite but max A is finite